# Young's double slit experiment viva question

Tags: optics, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

My professor asked me (in my viva exam), *"If, in the Fraunhofer single slit diffraction experiment, if we have 2 slits instead of one (at very short distances), What would happen?"*

I answered with "Young's double slit experiment intensity distribution". He said my answer was wrong. Out of curiosity, what is the right answer then?

Answer (score 1):

The intensity distribution will remain same as fraunhofer one only , however intensity will increase at each point . Means supposedly earlier there was Amplitude 2A , at a point of maxima , now it will become 4A , since 2 waves will come from the new fraunhofer slit also as it is not very distant from the previous slit , hence , you can assume the maximas and minimas of the new slit are located at same positions as of the previous slit .

So intensity will get 4 times at each place , but distribution will remain same .

Comment: But won't it simply be a superposition of 2 single slit diffraction patterns?

Comment: No , since both slits are a combination of many synchronised double slits .